# How do I prevent all action specific invocations in nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, nginx

I want to write a mapping rule to prevent the following routing errors in my Rails app which is front-ended by nginx.

Should I use the following rule to prevent the errors listed below?

```
if ($request_uri ~* "(*.action)" ) {
    return 444;
}
```

> production.log-20150419:ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [HEAD] "/index!download.action"):
>       production.log-20150419:ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [HEAD] "/index!execute.action"):
>       production.log-20150419:ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [HEAD] "/index!WCIndex.action"):
>       production.log-20150419:ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [HEAD] "/index!OAIndex.action"):
>       production.log-20150419:ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [HEAD] "/userInfoAction.action"):
>       production.log-20150419:ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [HEAD] "/admin/install!license.action"):
>       production.log-20150419:ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [HEAD] "/admin/index.action"):
>       production.log-20150419:ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [HEAD] "/license!getExpireDateOfDays.action"):